# How to get pixi-filters working?

Tags: javascript, typescript, pixi.js

I have imported both `pixi` and `pixi-filters` like so:

```
import 'pixi.js';
import 'pixi-filters';
```

However, after running the code:

```
const outlineFilterRed = new PIXI.filters.GlowFilter(15, 2, 1, 0xff9999, 0.5);
```

Following error is thrown:

> Property 'GlowFilter' does not exist on type 'typeof filters'.

What am I doing wrong?

**P.S**

I'm following this example: https://pixijs.github.io/examples/#/filters/outline-filter.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like every filter needs to be imported individually, like it's written in the [GlowFilter's README.md](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-filters/tree/master/filters/glow) on Github.

**Install:**

```
npm install @pixi/filter-glow
```

**Import:**

```
import { GlowFilter } from '@pixi/filter-glow';
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [definitions file](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-typescript/blob/v4.x/pixi-filters.d.ts), the GlowFilter (And other filters) do not exit. And according to the original [js library](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-filters) they should exist.

This simply means that the definitions files are out-dated.

You have two options:

- Add a local definitions to the PIXI.filters.
- Create a PR to the definitions repository. (BEST)

Comment: I doubt that it's a definitions' issue, because when I log the `PIXI.filters` object, it doesn't contain the `GlowFilter`

Comment: Well, that's a different issue... You probably did not include the `pixi-filters` in your bundle. How do you bundle your game?

Comment: I've found the issue, please check out my answer. Thanks for the suggestions though :)